# Need to block login page and homepage after successfully login using react and callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am a beginner in react. Whenever i am logging in i managed to redirect to dashboard. but when i type login url in browser it is coming back to login page. how to prevent it? I don't want my user to show login component and home page after he/she logs in only protected routes can be accessed.

App.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import DashBoard from './components/DashBoard';
import PrivateRoutes from './utils/PrivateRoutes';
import PublicRoutes from './utils/PublicRoutes';
function App() {
  const [isUserAuthenticated, setUserAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const userAuth = ()=>{
    setUserAuthenticated(!isUserAuthenticated)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header loggedIn={isUserAuthenticated} userAuth = {userAuth} />
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes isUserAuthenticated={isUserAuthenticated} />}>
            <Route element={<DashBoard />} path="/dashboard" exact/> 
          </Route>
          <Route element={<PublicRoutes isUserAuthenticated={isUserAuthenticated} />}>
          <Route element={<Home />} path="/" exact/>
          <Route element={<Login isUserAuthenticated = {isUserAuthenticated} userAuth = {userAuth} />} path="/login" exact/>
          </Route>
           
        </Routes> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PrivateRoutes.js

```
import {  Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react'

const PrivateRoutes = ({isUserAuthenticated}) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  
  return (
    isUserAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" state={{from:location}} replace />
  )
}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

PublicRoutes.js

```
import {  Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react'

const PublicRoutes = ({isUserAuthenticated}) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  
  return (
    (isUserAuthenticated===false) ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/dashboard" state={{from:location}} replace />
  )
}

export default PublicRoutes
```

Header.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container, Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
function Header({ loggedIn, userAuth }) {
  return (
    <Navbar bg='dark' expand='lg' variant="dark">
        <Container>
        <Link className='navbar-brand' to='/'>Server Tools</Link>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav" className="justify-content-end">
          <Nav className="ml-auto">
            {
               loggedIn? (
                <>
                <Link className='nav-link' to='/dashboard'>
                Dashboard
                </Link>
                <Link className='btn btn-success' onClick={()=>userAuth()} to='/'>
                LOGOUT
                </Link>
                </>
               ):(
                <Link className='btn btn-success' to='/login'>
                LOGIN
                </Link>
               )
            }
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
    </Navbar>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Login.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Container,Row, Col, Card,Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Navigate, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
const Login = ({isUserAuthenticated, userAuth}) => {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
  const [umessage, setUM] = useState("Your username must be: Admin")
  const [pmessage, setPM] = useState("Your password must be: Admin")
  const location = useLocation()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const from  = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/dashboard"
  
  const changeUsername = (e)=>{
    setUsername(e.target.value)

    if(e.target.value==="Admin"){
      setUM("Perfect")
    }
  }
  const changePassword = (e)=>{
    setPassword(e.target.value)

    if(e.target.value==="Admin"){
      setPM("Perfect")
    }
  }

  const enableButton = () =>{
    if(username==="Admin" && password==="Admin"){
      return false
    }
    return true
  }



  return (
    (isUserAuthenticated===false)
    ?<Container className='mt-5'>
      <Row>
        <Col md="3"></Col>
        <Col md="6">
          <Card>
            <Card.Header className='p-3' style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              <h4>LOGIN HERE</h4>
            </Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>
              <Form onSubmit={(e)=>{
                e.preventDefault()
                navigate(from, {replace:true})
                }}>
              <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="text" required="true" onChange={(e)=>changeUsername(e)} value={username} placeholder="Enter your username here" />
                <Form.Text>{umessage}</Form.Text>
                <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="password" required="true" onChange={(e)=>changePassword(e)} value={password} placeholder="Enter your password" />
                <Form.Text>{pmessage}</Form.Text>
                <Form.Control className='btn btn-block btn-primary mb-3' disabled={enableButton()} type='submit' onClick={()=>userAuth()} value="Login" />
              </Form.Group>
              </Form>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col md="3"></Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
    :<Navigate to="/dashboard" />
  )
}

export default Login
```

I have tried creating protected routes and public routes and i have shared whole code above.
My react app is restricting access to protected routes as expected.

I named Public routes but i want to control them after user login the user should not go back to login page.
and homepage.
after login.

It is working like user is logging in then going to dashboard again when user types url of login in browser he is again going back to to login page. this i do not want.

Comment: So you basically want the user to only see the protected routes once they are logged in & when you refresh or open a new tab in the browser with the same website after logging in, the data persists & the user is still authenticated. Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: yes absolutely correct

Comment: Well, you need to persist the authentication state somewhere, like Local/Session Storage. Otherwise, the data is going to be reset once you refresh the page or open it in a new tab. You can, for example, use `userAuth()` function value to set a specific key in Local Storage that specifies whether a user is logged in or not. That will keep the data persistent.

Comment: In a real world scenario, you'll usually communicate with a backend and receive some sort of token that you can communicate with the backend later. You often store that token encrypted in Local Storage for communication & recheck every time the app is loaded whether the user is authenticated or not with this token. That is assuming you're building the usual SPA.